# c# generics access of class properties

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have a class "MyClass" which implements generics .

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
   T _base;

   MyClass(T child) { _base = child; }
   void asdf() 
   {
      _base.MasterFunction();
      _base.Variable = true;
   }
}
```

How can I implement the class so that I can access the members of the class im passing in "T"?

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass<Master>();
mc.asdf(this);
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. You forgot to make `asdf` public. Unless you are asking why you can't access the private method from another instance of the same type?

Comment: Add an interface containing `MasterFunction()` and `Variable` and ensure `T` implements it.

Comment: I just realized that the text asks one thing but the code shows a different thing - *what* are you asking? How to call members of T from inside `MyClass` ? Or how to call `asdf()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
public class DbException<T> where T : BaseItem
```

In this case - BaseItem is the generic type that You want Your generic method to operate on

Comment: this is almost it. but the BaseItem can be multiples. How would I do that?

Comment: The only way then - is to use interfaces. where T : ITest, IBase, IMyOtherThing

Comment: in case You're wondering why - it's because C# does not support multiple inheritance for classes. Only interface`s

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Start();
}

public class AutoStarter<T> where T : ICar
{
    public AutoStarter(T car)
    {
        car.Start();  //It knows that T implements interface ICar, so you can call Start
    }
}
```

You can use interface constraint, base class.. You can find it here:

[MSDN where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

[MSDN Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)